# Vue router shows only one component

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I'm making a login application with `Login` and `ResetPassword` components. Currently, my `Login` component displays correctly. However, when I try to go to my `/reset-password` route, it only shows my `Login` component. I cannot get the content of my `ResetPassword` component to display no matter what I do. Am I missing something?

### Directory structure

The structure of my `src` directory (minus assets and shims`:

```
src/
├── App.vue
├── components
│   ├── HelloWorld.vue
│   ├── Login.vue
│   └── ResetPassword.vue
├── main.ts
├── plugins
│   └── vuetify.ts
├── router
│   └── index.ts
└── views
    ├── About.vue
    ├── Home.vue
    └── ResetPasswordPage.vue
```

### `main.ts`

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import * as config from '../config.json'
import vuetify from './plugins/vuetify'

Vue.config.productionTip = false
Vue.prototype.$secureCookies = config.secureCookies
Vue.prototype.$secureApi = config.secureApi
Vue.prototype.$hostApi = config.hostApi
Vue.prototype.$domain = config.domain

new Vue({
  router,
  vuetify,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

### `App.vue`

*Note*: I am using the Login component here.

```html
<template>
  <v-app>
    <v-main>
      <Login/>
    </v-main>
  </v-app>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import Vue from 'vue'
import Login from './components/Login.vue'

export default Vue.extend({
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    Login
  },

  data: () => ({
    //
  })
})
</script>
```

### `router/index.ts`

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter, { RouteConfig } from 'vue-router'
import Home from '../views/Home.vue'
import ResetPasswordPage from '../views/ResetPasswordPage.vue'
import About from '../views/About.vue'

Vue.use(VueRouter)

const routes: Array<RouteConfig> = [
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'Home',
    component: Home
  },
  {
    path: '/about',
    name: 'About',
    component: About
  },
  {
    path: '/reset-password',
    name: 'Reset Password',
    component: ResetPasswordPage
  },
  {
    path: '*',
    redirect: '/'
  }
]

const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes
})

export default router
```

### `components/ResetPassword.vue` stub

```html
<template>
</template>
<script lang="ts">

import { Component, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator'
import fetch from 'node-fetch'
import VueCookies from 'vue-cookies'

Vue.use(VueCookies)

@Component
export default class ResetPassword extends Vue {
  //
}
</script>
```

### `components/Login.vue` stub

```html
<template>
</template>
<script lang="ts">

import { Component, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator'
import fetch from 'node-fetch'
import VueCookies from 'vue-cookies'

Vue.use(VueCookies)

@Component
export default class Login extends Vue {
  //
}
</script>
```

### Versions

| Tool | Version |
| --- | --- |
| TypeScript | 3.9.3 |
| Vue | 2.6.11 |
| Vuetify | 2.4.0 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `router-view` component to render the current route component instead of `<Login/>`

App.vue

```
<template>
  <v-app>
    <v-main>
      <router-view/>
    </v-main>
  </v-app>
</template>
```

then just add your login route to the routes definition:

router/index.ts :

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter, { RouteConfig } from 'vue-router'
import Home from '../views/Home.vue'
import ResetPasswordPage from '../views/ResetPasswordPage.vue'
import About from '../views/About.vue'
import Login from '../components/Login.vue'
Vue.use(VueRouter)

const routes: Array<RouteConfig> = [
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'Home',
    component: Home
  },
  {
    path: '/about',
    name: 'About',
    component: About
  },
  {
    path: '/login',
    name: 'Login',
    component: Login
  },
  {
    path: '/reset-password',
    name: 'Reset Password',
    component: ResetPasswordPage
  },

  {
    path: '*',
    redirect: '/'
  }
]
```